# No Birdsmouth on Rafters - is there a way to remedy this?

Tags: framing, roofing

I just got a new house and I'm fixing up the garage. I've noticed there aren't any birdsmouth cuts on the rafters and instead, they used wedges.

They tried to remedy it with some ties, but I don't think these are adequate.

Any Suggestions? Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Since it's new, was it inspected and did it meet local codes? If so, then it should be OK, but if the inspector noted the issue, do you have recourse from the seller? Any DIY change might void the chance of the *seller* fixing it.

Comment: One of those ties is doing nothing, another is barely doing anything, and the third has 1 nail doing nothing and one nail-hole that missed the rafter entirely. They need to be anchored to the plates, not to a vertical 2x4 that isn't particularly attached to the structure so it will fly away with the roof. If there IS a local authority having jurisdiction with an inspector, I'd ask them just what was going on here.

Comment: How old is this garage?

Comment: When I say "new" house, I mean we just purchased it. It's actually an older house. I believe the previous owner fixed up the garage in 2011 based on the osb date. Appreciate the comments. I didn't think those ties were doing much. I was hoping there was another tie that could help support it better. My building inspector didn't mention it.

Comment: Is the garage attached to the house, or freestanding?

Comment: On the second picture, is that two toe nails intended to fasten the rafter to the top plate?

Comment: The sheathing on the roof is what transfers wind loads from the face of that wall to the perpendicular walls at the ends of your garage. The toe nails (3-16d box nails or 3-10d common nails from the IRC's Table R602.3(1)) that didn't sink into the top plate normally transfer the wind load into the roof sheathing. There's a risk of the top of your wall toppling inward under that wind pressure. You can imagine uplift reducing the friction along the top plate as wind pressure simultaneously pushes on the top of that wall.

Comment: Oof, what a mess. If you bring it to the attention of a code enforcement they could possibly condemn the garage until this is addressed.

Comment: @popham That was probably the intention, but from the looks of it, there isn't much actual fastening going on.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Blocks are fine for vertical load, and you should have rafter ties carrying horizontal load. (I'm referring to horizontal lumber, not the hurricane clips described above as "ties".) I'm not sure your concern is warranted.

Comment: @isherwood, if that 2nd photo is representative of the fastening of all rafters to the top plate, then there's no shear transfer there. Imagine a 50 year wind storm pushing on the face of that wall from the outside. How does that wind's thrust reach the foundation without the shear transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there aren't roofers or 30" of snow on the roof, remove the hurricane ties, remove the blocking between rafters (save the material for reinstallation if your rafters are taller than 10"), and remove the wedges.

Install a third top plate that is beveled to match the slope of the rafters. You can blunt the tip of the bevel to avoid interfering with the mess of old toe nails, but only if the length of the bearing surface is at least 1-1/2" long in compliance with the IRC's [bearing length minimum](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.6). If there's a rafter tie (a horizontal member spanning from one exterior wall to its opposite exterior wall) in the way, then butt the top plate into the rafter tie and continue on its other side. Follow the fastener schedule from [IRC Table R602.3(1)](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3) to fasten this "top plate" to the top plate below it. Toe nail the rafters down to the beveled top plate following the fastener schedule from IRC Table R602.3(1) again.

If your rafters are more than 10" tall, then reinstall the blocking that you removed earlier. This is for compliance with the IRC's [lateral support requirements](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.8).

If your region calls for hurricane ties (which it probably does judging by those existing ones), then install them following the manufacturer's recommendations. If the ones you have cannot be installed following the manufacturer's recommendations, then take them back and get ones that can be installed following the manufacturer's recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you're stuck with fixing this yourself (wasn't clear in the initial question. House is only new-to-you and your house inspector, as they usually do from what I've seen, overlooked a glaring issue. See about getting a refund from your house inspector, at least.)

The roof has apparently been sitting there OK since 2011, from what you say, so preventing it from flying off to Oz in a windstorm seems like the biggest need, and for that, there are framing reinforcements a lot longer than those hurricane ties (that are barely any use as installed.)  On the generic end, there's the stuff that came before official hurricane ties, galvanized steel plumbing strap, which you can get in a 100-foot roll and use to attach the rafters to the plates, or even the studs below the plates. Do that the same way that hurricane ties are installed (so the roof has to shear the nails, rather than having a way to pull them out)

The [Simpson H6](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/uxpkvc9ke9/C-C-2021-p276-278.pdf) hurricane tie is over 19 inches long, as opposed to about 6" for what look to be H2.5A ties you have there. They will probably make code officals (and where have they been for 12 years?) happy if that's a concern.

Comment: The hurricane ties are good for uplift. What about wind pressure on the exterior wall? His image of the rafter toe nailed into the top plate seems to show only 2 fasteners, where at least one of them didn't sink into the top plate at all. IRC calls for 3-16d box nails or 3-10d common nails to hold the wall up.

Comment: Those fasteners transfer pressure from the face of that wall up to the rafters. From the rafters, the roof sheathing transfers the load to the ends of the building. At the ends of the building, the wall sheathing transfers the load down to the foundation.